# how to cat/grep string semicolon delimited

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How to cat/grep string into several files semicolon delimited to capture mac address. Example:

Folder:

```
 /home/acl
```

acl Files:

```
 acl1
 acl2
```

string format info acl files:

```
 a;mac address;ip address;hostname
```

example acl1 file:

```
 a;14:cc:20:00:73:02;192.168.1.150;CONTA1
```

example acl2 file:

```
 a;13:aa:10:10:74:01;192.168.1.140;FINANCE2
```

Attempts

```
 grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' acl1
```

Out (expected result)

```
 13:aa:10:10:74:01
```

Is there any simple way to integrate this result into a variable?

Example:

```
acl="grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' acl*"
```

thanks

PD: Hard choise. Both solutions are correct, but I must choose one. I thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to extract mac, use `awk` and `;` as separator

```
awk -F\; '{print $2}' acl?
```

where

- `-F\;` use `;` as separator, `;` need to be escaped.
- `'{print $2}'` print second field

to put into a var use

```
var=$(awk -F\; '{print $2}' acl?)
```

or

```
var=$(awk -F\; '{printf "%s%s",sep, $2; sep="," ;}' acl?)
```

and use `"$var"` in command line.

Note that it depends on how you can feed multiple mac to `arpfilter`.

Comment: ok. out perfect, but how do I put that in a variable?

Comment: Hard choise. Both solutions are correct, but I must choose one. I thank you all

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **Archemar** response you can use **xargs** to change your arptables in a single line within multiple acl files :

```
awk -F\; '{print $2}' acl? | xargs -I {} arptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING --source-mac {} -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hard choise. Both solutions are correct, but I must choose one. I thank you all